# bash command sed is outputting an unexpected error

Tags: bash, sed, sh

I'm trying replace a word in a file using `sed`. 
In the same `bash` script I use the command :

```
sed -i "s/${list[$index]}/${phone}/g" $1
```

And it's working flawlessly on the first function, but the second function I wrote:

```
sed -i "s/${list[$index]}/${zipcode}/g" $1
```

Outputs this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

I'm really desperate, I'm pretty sure that it's a dumb mistake I'm doing but I can't sort it out

Comment: is something like this zipcode=4763A5 it does not contains any special char, it contains only hex chars. The same applies to phone

Comment: Nope, only hex chars there too. I find it really strange because they are the same almost a copy/paste

Comment: Try with a different sed command separator (i.e `sed -i "s|${list[$index]}|${zipcode}|g" $1`). Also try to remove `-i` switch for testing and also try to replace `$1` with the real file. Switch `-i` will not work if `$1` is not a real valid file (avoid also relative paths)

Comment: Please include the *exact* output of `printf '%q\n' "${list[$index]}" "${phone}" "${zipcode}"` in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I tried your code but it doesn't work. The error is: sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Is this on macOS? If so, use `sed -i.bak -e "s/../../"`. Your command currently only works on GNU.

Comment: @thatotherguy but OP mentioned the first command as working...

Comment: Given that error, it looks like `${list[$index]}` is the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

When the first half of a `sed` ***s**ubstitute* command is empty:

```
sed 's//foo/' <<< bar
```

It returns this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

Therefore, [as William Pursell commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43257585/bash-command-sed-is-outputting-an-unexpected-error#comment73591631_43257585), there's a value of the `${list[@]}` array that's empty, or maybe `$index` is out of the array's range.